# Git Workflow Example

Tags: git, workflow

Here's my application folder structure:

```
root
|--applications
   |--Production
   |--Beta
   |--Development
```

Is there a way to set up a Git repo to track the changes in each version via a branch? Then when I've got changes in coming out of development, I could just merge them into Beta. Then after they've been tested by the beta team I can merge them into production?

Does anybody know of any examples for how I could set this up? Or am I going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't know schema, this can help you to more understand easily the git flow concept :

[image]

You use system branch of git for differents work environnement. Not all the branch to create is from master. Master is just branch for you code in production. You can use other branch "develop" for create lot of others working branch without touch master branch.

**You can consider the git branch as like an environnement code also environnement "server".**

*This is not the exaclty  definition but is the best way to more understand git flow...*

Comment: Thanks darkomen, I'm going to fork production to beta then fork beta for development. then when if comes time to push out the new changes i'll use pull requests.

Answer (score 0):

With git, different branches do not generally track changes in different directories. You can indeed have develop, beta, production, etc. branches, and merge how you described (though you may want to take a look [here](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) for another way to do it), but you just want **one** directory for all these branches. So instead of changing directories when you want to work on a different branch, you just switch branches. You can do this with git because switching branches is very quick (unlike, say, Subversion, where switching revisions can be slow).